# Can FtpWebRequest get a file above the root folder?

Tags: c#, ftp, ftpwebrequest

When I open a request to a server it opens to a default directory (user directory).

I want to get a file that is in a completely different path.

```
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://" + txtHost.Text);
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xxxx", "yyyy");
            request.UseBinary = true;
            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Now the request points to 
'\user\ssfactor'
and I want a file in 
'\factor\dktest\pdi'

Is this possible?

If not, can someone offer me another programmatic way? I tried Ssh.Net, but it only seems to work on ssh servers.

Comment: Sure, just add `/%2E%2E` (one directory) `/%2E%2E/%2E%2E` (two back) as part of the request (if I understand you) correctly.

Comment: This totally depends on how the FTP server at the other end is configured. And frankly, if the FTP is configured to allow you to navigate up a directory it is probably configured incorrectly.

Comment: Çöđěxěŕ - I tried the path 'ftp://10.0.0.4/%2E%2E/%2E%2E/factor/dktest/pdi" which should take it to the path but got a (550) File unavailable error.

Comment: iakobski - You are probably right. It seems like the whole server is pretty much open to ftp. It's why I am having trouble, all the internet examples seem to assume there is only one 'ftp path'.

Comment: I typed FTP into the nuget browser and a couple options came up (probably should have done that initially). I installed FluentFTP and it seems to do the trick: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41460069/download-files-using-fluentftp